# React native for iOS - CFBundleIdentifier does not exist

Tags: ios, react-native, nem

I'm trying to run my app with react-native run-ios command but its showing the following error:

> Found Xcode project AliceMobile.xcodeproj Building using "xcodebuild
>   -project AliceMobile.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme AliceMobile -destination id=165690EB-E924-498B-A72D-9D939D93D467
>   -derivedDataPath build" User defaults from command line:
>
> IDEDerivedDataPathOverride =
>   /Users/itegra/Desktop/Developer/Alice/alice-platform/Services/AliceMobile/ios/build
>
> note: Using new build system
>
> 2018-10-10 11:39:37.889 xcodebuild[63241:2936081] unexpected response:
>   ErrorResponse(description: "unknown error while handling message:
>   missingWorkspaceContext")
>
> error: Build service could not start build operation: internal error:
>   failed to send the system info to the build service
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AliceMobile.app
>   An error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22): Failed to install the requested
>   application The bundle identifier of the application could not be
>   determined. Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value
>   for CFBundleIdentifier. Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not
>   Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AliceMobile.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c
>   Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AliceMobile.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:602:13) at Object.execFileSync
>   (child_process.js:622:13) at Promise.then
>   (/Users/itegra/Desktop/Developer/Alice/alice-platform/Services/AliceMobile/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
>   at

Someone could help me?